# Accessing newer APIs in a redirected assembly

Tags: .net, reflection

If I use Assembly Binding Redirection to redirect my v1.0 referenced assembly to a v1.1 assembly, can I use reflection APIs to:

- Create new classes introduced in the v1.1 assembly
- Invoke new methods of existing classes introduced in the v1.1 assembly

While keeping reference to the v1.0 assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmm,  I'm not sure if this makes sense.

You could do what you say but you would need to know the class names and methods available at 1.1 while coding against the 1.0 version so you why not to change to the 1.1 references?

You can create instances with name using the Activatior.CreateInstance().